# Evaluation of integrals - how to set the vertical line when there are brackets?

Tags: formatting

I got the command

```
\def\at{
  \left.
    \vphantom{\int}
  \right|
}
```

from another question on steckexchange to set the evaluation line at integrals - which works fine in general but if there are brackets, there is too much space between the bracket and the line. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: You could add negative space with e.g. `\!` or `\hspace{ }`

Comment: Yeah, but then it doesn't look right when there is no bracket.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\biggr|` instead of `\left.\right|`.  I while I only applied that advice to the vertical bar, the same argument could apply to the parens (though I would use `\Bigl(...\Bigr)` in this case).

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\at{
  \left.
    \vphantom{\int}
  \right|
}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\at_0^1
\]
\[
\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\biggr|_0^1
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using ```\biggr``` instead of ```\at```, I get "! Missing delimiter (. inserted). <to be read again>". I'm using the ```scrartcl``` class.

Comment: @Thomas Perhaps you have a typo.  What I am advocating, if you wanted to replace your `\at` macro, is `\def\at{\biggr|}`

Comment: Yes, I forgot the |. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a remember for the future. There is an old package of the 12/12/2012 called `physics` and it is not much used because there are spacing problems in some situation. I think at least for this command `\eval` there are no problems. Here there is my short proposal:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\[=16\eval(-\frac 12\sin x\cos x+\frac x2\biggr)|_0^\pi\]
\end{document}
```

[image]